# Fresh install of Ubuntu server 22.04 wont boot fully. looking for /usr (booting from software raid)

Tags: ubuntu, grub, boot-loader

I have a dell C4140 that I am installing ubuntu server 22.04 on. In the installer, I set up 2 drives as boot devices (the system has 2 nvme drives 500GB) so that UEFI can access either drive (that ESP partition). I then set up a LVM volume on top of a RAID0 array using the rest of the space on both drives. I format it as ext4 and set it to "/". on reboot, I get an error shown in the screenshots and cannot seem to boot fully. I know the bootloader picks up, but it is waiting to mount /usr. [image]

[image]
[image]
I have no idea how to fix this. I have reinstalled using different techniques a dozen times. I would like to stripe both drives as there is no need for redundancy and I could use the speed.

Comment: I take it you choose to have separate filesystems for /, /home, /usr etc? by the way, the alert is saying that you don't have a disk with that specified id - is that the /usr disk?

Comment: I did not actually. I just specified "/" and "/boot/efi" the /proc/cmdline refers to the uuid of /dev/sda3, which I think is wrong. but no idea how to fix, or how it got that way

Comment: even specifically setting /usr to a partition result in the same error.

Comment: oh, I would never specifically set `/usr` to a separate partition for `/` - since modern linux symlinks `/bin => /usr/bin` and `/sbin => /usr/sbin` - you don't want `/usr` separate from `/` - not sure why you seem to be in that situation - but then, ubuntu, am I right

Comment: I would never do that normally, but I was just trying to test as to why I am getting this issue. I just tried a regular ubuntu install on a single drive using the OOTB drive config and still get the same issue.